# How to count the number of diagonal lines (consisting of 1s) in matrices with zeros and ones

Tags: r, matrix

I have matrices with randomly allocated 0 or 1 in each cell of the matrix. A 5 by 5 matrix may look like this:

```
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    0    1    1
[5,]    1    1    0    1    0
```

generated, for example, by the code:

```
mm <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
A<-apply(mm, c(1, 2), function(x) sample(c(0, 1), 1))
```

Diagonal lines consist of 1s in the following way:

[image]

i.e., there are 3 diagonal lines of length 2, and 2 diagonal lines of length 3. Moreover, there are no diagonal lines of length 4 and 5.

I would store this result in an array `v`:

```
v
[1] 3 2 0 0
```

i.e. `v[1]` stores diagonal lines of length 2, `v[2]` stores diagonal lines of length 3 and so on.

My attempt has been wrong. It based on:

```
which(A!=0)
 [1]  4  5  8  9 10 11 12 13 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

In this array:

```
4 8 12
```

and

```
5 9 13
```

correspond to 2 diagonal lines of length 3. The 3 diagonal lines of length 2 are:

```
18 22
19 23
20 24
```

(I checked for the numbers that differ by 4). But if there are columns of all 1s, this method does not work (try with `A[5,5]<-1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`row(A) + col(A)` is constant on antidiagonals so:

```
tabulate_runs <- function(x, n) {
  tab <- with(rle(x), tabulate(lengths[values == 1]))
  replace(integer(n), seq_along(tab), tab)
 }
rowSums(simplify2array(tapply(A, row(A) + col(A), tabulate_runs, nrow(A))))[-1]
## [1] 3 2 0 0
```

### Note

The code to produce `A` in the question is not reproducible because it uses random numbers without setting the seed so for reproducbility we used this:

```
A <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L))
```